# Filtering in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, filtering

From the given setup

```
IEnumerable<int> one = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

IEnumerable<int> two = new int[] { 12, 34, 56, 7, 8 };


MySet[] sets
= new MySet[]
{ 
   new MySet{ MySetID =100, MySubSet=new MySubSet{SubSet=new List<int>(one), 
   SubSetID=1212}},

   new MySet{ MySetID =101, MySubSet=new MySubSet{SubSet=new List<int>(two),
   SubSetID=1414}}
};
```

How can i filter out even numbers from "SubSet"s

```
 var GetSet = 
     from mysets in sets 
    where (P => mysets.MySubSet.SubSet.FindAll(???? ))
    select mysets;
```

Comment: It's really not clear what results you want. A "where" clause will only include or exclude the existing MySet instances. Are you trying to find MySet instances which don't have any even numbers? If you want to perform a projection, you should be using select rather than where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? Your question is rather confusingly worded, but I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
var query = from mySet in sets
            select new MySet {
                MySetID = mySet.ID,
                MySubSet = new MySubSet {
                    SubSet = mySet.MySubSet.SubSet.Where(p => p % 2 == 0).ToList(),
                    SubSetID = mySet.MySubSet.SubSetID
                }
            };
```

So I am interpreting your question to mean that you want to filter out the even numbers from `MySubSet.SubSet` in each instance of `MySet`.

Comment: Bit correction you are filtering out odd numbers,i need even numbers,would you mind asking to change p=>p%2!=0  to p=>p%2==0 ?

Comment: @russeuludana: You said "filter out even numbers." I interpreted this to mean that you wanted to exclude the even numbers; i.e., you only wanted to see the odd numbers. I have made the change that you requested.

Comment: I am getting Error " Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'. "  in select statement.

Comment: @russeludana: You need to invoke `ToList` as I caught in my last edit but did not point out that I made the change.

Comment: @Jason - is this possible with linq to sql?